# SQL Server Change Data Capture does not capture all delete events

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have a table that has been marked for SQL Change Data capture. However, I intermittently(very low frequency, one event per week) see delete events not being captured in the change tables. I have been unable to find a cause for this to occur. Under what scenarios could I have these events being missed from the CDC tables?

Comment: CDC happens asynchronously from the transactions it tracks. In high volume environments, that means CDC can sometimes need time to "catch up" to the underlying changes that happened. Any discrepancies I've ever encountered were always timing issues; I haven't encountered an actual data loss. Could you flesh out your question with more details that have lead you to believe transactions are being missed?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. I think it started after we applied some patches. Were you able to find a root cause or fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should check SQL Server job execution history. A job should be named something like **cdc.[your_db_name]_capture**. Has it any erros? This job must be enabled.